# Can't get Volumetric Lighting to work

Tags: lighting

I'm trying out the blender 2.80 for the first time and was trying to get a volumetric lighting in my scene with a light house. I've got the volume scatter shader on my World and set the light strenght to one thousand. Is there something that I'm missing? How do I make the effect more intense so that I can really see the spot light.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you click the volumentrics checkbox on the render tab?

Comment: Yes it's checked, though I've been using EEVEE as my render engine. Trying to change back to cycles but having lots of problems with meshes deforming in rendered view... I figured cycles would be easier to make volumentric lighting work maybe?